# Detecting (Multiple) QR Codes with ZXing

Tags: java, qr-code, zxing

I'm writing a small java program that will detect a QR code in a given image, then decode it and print out the result (assuming the QR code contains a string). Ideally, I'd like to be able to extend this to detect and decode multiple QR codes from a single image.

A quick google led me to the [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) library, but all of the documentation and tutorials I've found so far relate specifically to Android. Are there any docs/tutorials out there that will help me, or do I need to trudge through the [project api](http://zxing.org/w/docs/javadoc/index.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, most of it is pure Java, with several platform specific clients. Use the code in `core/`, which is not Android-specific. You want [`QRCodeMultiReader`](http://zxing.org/w/docs/javadoc/com/google/zxing/multi/qrcode/QRCodeMultiReader.html). It is really no different than the other `Reader`s, nothing much more to know.

Comment: Are there any tutorials that can get me started? Such as how to convert an image to a [`BinaryBitmap`](http://zxing.org/w/docs/javadoc/com/google/zxing/BinaryBitmap.html), to pass to the `Reader`?

Comment: Look at the source code? that's probably the best tutorial of all.